# Crashing on reconciliation of large group name

Tags: c++, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, tivoli-identity-manager

I don't have very much knowledge of C++ and Lotus notes. I have piece of code which prints the group name in log.

```
Util::AgentDebug("In Command::InitGroupMap(): Group Name = %s",lnGrpName.GetBuf());
```

lnGrpName is LNstring. it is working fine but whenever group name length is more than 2200, then it crashes.

here is the example - suppose group name is

> asd.Storage.Implementation; task-mnncpohcpg01; task-paersc2hcpg01; azscotns02a; azscotns02b; ctshelns02a; ctshelns02b; flschons03a; flschons03b; iadubqns02a; iadubqns02b; mnncpoba0015; mnncpobrcd01; mnncpoisobrcd01; mnncpoisobrcd02; mnncpoisov7k01; mnncpolto01; mnncpolto01_1; mnncpolto01_imc; mnncpons03a; mnncpons03b; mnncpons900a_asd; mnncpons900b_asd; mnncpons900c; mnncpons900c_asd; mnncpons900d; mnncpons900d_asd; mnncpons900_asd; mnncpons900_sw1; mnncpons900_sw2; mnncposanc100; mnncposanc200; mnncposanr150; mnncposanr250; mnncposvc01; MNNCPOFL9KR01; MNNCPOFL9KR02; MNNCPONS900_sw1; MNNCPONS900_sw2; njmadins01a; njmadins01b; njros1ns05ta; njros1ns05tb; njwoodns05a; njwoodns05b; NJCTMVSP01; p2erscba0145; paersc1ns900a_asd; paersc1ns900b_asd; paersc1ns900c; paersc1ns900d; paersc1ns900_sw1; paersc1ns900_sw2; paersc2ns900a_asd; paersc2ns900b_asd; paersc2ns900c; paersc2ns900d; paersc2ns900_sw1; paersc2ns900_sw2; paersc2ocum01; paersc2opm01; paerscns05; paerscnsv501a; paerscnsv501b; PACTMVSP01; PAERSC1FL9KR01; PAERSC1FL9KR02; PAERSC1LABBRCD01; PAERSC1LABBRCD02; PAERSC1LABSVC01; PAERSC2FL9KR01; PAERSC2FL9KR02; PAERSC2FL9KR03; PAERSC2LABBRCD01; PAERSC2LABBRCD02; PAERSC2LABSVC01; txdallns02a; txdallns02b; MNNCPOBA0014; paerscsvc03; njros1svc01; njros1svc02; p1ehowld202; p1ehowld203; p2ehowld202; p2ehowld203; mnncpold202; mnncpold203; MNNCPONS805_asd; MNNCPONS805a_asd; MNNCPONS805b_asd; MNNCPONS805b_asd; paersc2ns805_asd; paersc2ns805a_asd; paersc2ns805b_asd; mnncpob15k01; paersc1g15k01; paersc2g15k01; paersc2sane103; paersc2sane203; P2ERSCBA0305; MNNCPOBA0277; P2ERSCAPL0005; MNNCPOAPL0016; p2erscba0147; mnncpoba0016; MNNCPOECSCN01; PAERSC2ECSCN01; PAERSC2FLAR900_1; P2ERSCAPL0006; njros1labcisc100; njros1labcisc200; p1erscba0402; paersc2ns700_sw1; paersc2ns700_sw2; paersc2ns700a_asd; paersc2ns700b_asd; paersc2ns700_asd; paersc1ns700_sw1; paersc1ns700_sw2; paersc1ns700a_asd; paersc1ns700b_asd; paersc1ns700_asd; mnncpons700_sw1; mnncpons700_sw1; mnncpons700_sw2; mnncpons700a_asd; mnncpons700b_asd; mnncpons700c_asd; mnncpons700d_asd; mnncpons700_asd; p2erscba0346; p2erscba0146; paersc1ns500; paersc1ns500a_asd; paersc1ns500b_asd; paersc2ns500; paersc2ns500a_asd; paersc2ns500b_asd

is this issue because of LNString or GetBuf()?

AgentDebug method is below -

```
void Util::AgentDebug( wchar_t * format , ... )
 {

wchar_t     tmp[2048];
va_list     args;
char        strBuff[4096];
int         j = 0;

va_start(args, format);
vswprintf_s(tmp, format, args);
va_end(args);

int cnt = wcstombs(strBuff, tmp, 4095);
if(cnt < 0)
{
    char *strInput = (char*)tmp;
    for( int i = 0; i < (wcslen(tmp) * 2); i++ )
    {
        if(strInput[i] != 0)
            strBuff[j++] = strInput[i];
    }
    strBuff[j] = '\0';
}
// AdkDebug (strBuff);
// Fix for IY98698 Certain Chinese character throws exception during recon (PMR10927999672)
// String to be logged is passed as second argument
AdkDebug("%s",strBuff);


 }// end of func AgentDebug()
  // end S15302
```

what is the alternative of this because i want to print group name in log.

Comment: You have a group name that is longer than 2200? Really?  In any case, you really should show us the stack trace that you get from the crash. That will help give clues where your problem is.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I have edited the question please check it. Customer is giving name like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks a lot more like a group membership list than a group name, but okay...

I'm pretty rusty on my C++ and va_args stuff, but it looks to me like your tmp array can only hold 2048 wchar_t, and I assume that you need one wchar_t for the null terminator and you've got about 40 characters in your format string. So you're overflowing tmp when you pass in a string with length 2200. You'll overflow it with anything with a length that's longer than 2007 -- if I counted right.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the same thing?  A Group name as long as 2200 bytes or chars?  Ok.  I don't know how to "fix" your issue, but assuming you can't really "fix" it, to "fix" it I would either truncate the string or add the string as two values.  If the string is longer than 2150, break it up into two strings and write both of them to the log.  Just a thought.  Can't do more without more info.